# using jquery, what is the easiest way to replicate the wikipedia menu (with arrows)

Tags: jquery, navigation, wikipedia

i want to replicate the menu [on the left hand side of wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page)

is there any jquery plugin that exists to do the expand and collapse or do i have to write it from scratch?

In particular, i want the right and down arrows to show to indicate that this is a clickable menu

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('selector').slideToggle('fast');
```

See jQuery's documentation for more info: http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

Try this out:

```
<div class="title">Title</div>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="title">Title</div>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
.title
{
    padding-left:10px;
    background-image: url("ui/right_arrow.png") no-repeat;
}
.title.selected
{
    background-image: url("ui/down_arrow.png") no-repeat;
}
```

And your jQuery:

```
$('.title').live('click', function ()
{
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Comment: thanks . . how would i get the right and down arrows like they have it on WIKIpedia so its clear you can click on the link

Comment: You can use a background image on the divs with the "title" class, and use padding-left:10px or so to push the text away from the image, so the text doesn't sit on top of the image. You can then use the "toggleClass" method of jQuery to add/remove a "selected" class. The selected class can override the background image of the title, and show a different image. Let me know if you'd like an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use the accordion widget in the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) and style it as you like. Or you could use the toggle effect.